# Как картинку разместить позади параграфа?

Tags: html, css

Такой эффект хочу получить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.client p{
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: 'Italic';
    font-weight: bold;
}

.coment{
    background: url(https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/1/03cf72290cca88cdbd8724270cb30430-full.png) no-repeat;
}


/*End Client*/
```

```html
<div class="client">
            <h1>Our Clients Say</h1>
            <div class="coment">
            <p>Suspendisse sollicitudin velit sed leo. Ut<br>
            pharetra augue nec augue. Nam elit agna,<br> 
            endrerit sit amet, tincidunt, viverra sed,<br> 
            nulla. Donec porta diam eu massa.</p>
            
            <p>Quisque diam lorem, interdum vitae, dapibus<br>
             ac, scelerisque vitae, pede. Donec eget tellus<br>
              non erat lacinia fermentum. Donec in velit<br>
               vel ipsum auctor pulvinar. </p>
               </div>
                           <span>Bradley Grosh,<br>
                    Company Name</span>
        </div>
```

Получается вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что именно? не понятно...

Comment: Измените заголовок вопроса. Смеюсь, не могу думать.

Comment: @Air Первый большей скрин это то как я хочу что бы получилось, и скинул код, ну как видишь у меня не получается

Comment: @Igor Блин а ты прав ахахах

Answer (score 5, accepted):

всего то надо было с padding-ОМ поиграть да height: 250px выставить как, благо подсказал – vp_arth....

```css
.client p{
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: 'Italic';
    font-weight: bold;
}

.coment{
height: 250px;
padding:30px;
    background: url(https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/1/03cf72290cca88cdbd8724270cb30430-full.png) no-repeat;
   
    
}


/*End Client*/
```

```html
<div class="client">
            <h1>Our Clients Say</h1>
            <div class="coment">
            <p>Suspendisse sollicitudin velit sed leo. Ut<br>
            pharetra augue nec augue. Nam elit agna,<br> 
            endrerit sit amet, tincidunt, viverra sed,<br> 
            nulla. Donec porta diam eu massa.</p>
            
            <p>Quisque diam lorem, interdum vitae, dapibus<br>
             ac, scelerisque vitae, pede. Donec eget tellus<br>
              non erat lacinia fermentum. Donec in velit<br>
               vel ipsum auctor pulvinar. </p>
               </div>
                           <span>Bradley Grosh,<br>
                    Company Name</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: А куда девается хвостик от катринки который в низу?

Comment: aaaaa, хвостик нужен? )))  щас

Comment: @BraFik, просто не хватает высоты блока

Comment: @Air, хвостик там уже есть, в картинке) `height: 250px`

Comment: @vp_arth, благодарю, я даже не заметил..)))

Comment: @vp_arth, если бы ты не подсказал, я уже собирался псевдоэлементами заняться))))  еще раз благодарю))))

Answer (score 0):

уберите фиксированный height и добавьте background-size: contain;